# open html page from memory

Tags: html, vba

Is there a way to open html page from vba directly in default browser? I don't want to create a form and use webbrowser or similar component.
The idea is open external browser and write page in it somehow...

Comment: you can invoke the Internet Explorer object quite easily and target that. Never tried opening other browsers from VBS/VBA etc

Comment: Is IE the only way?

Comment: You can use `wscript.shell` to open Google Chrome quite easily and run a particular url. Not tried with Firefox or other. As to whether or not you can manipulate the DOM in the newly opened window I do not know as not tested

Answer (score 1):

To open a predefined URL in a named browser you can use VBScript like this:

```
Dim strURL: strURL="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67530458/open-html-page-from-memory"
Dim iState:iState=3
Dim bWait:bWait=true

Set oWS=CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

oWS.Run "chrome -url " & strURL,iState,bWait
oWS.Run "firefox -url " & strURL,iState,bWait

set oWS=nothing
```

If you omit the browser name it should invoke the default browser.

It is years since I used VBA but I'm fairly confident the approach is very similar in VBA.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have predefined URL.
I need something like webbrawser.document.write() but in external brawser

Comment: It is easy to do that with the IE object... when I get 5 mins I'll maybe have a try with Chrome